# How to select MIN only for values that have not been selected as MIN for previous records?

Tags: sql, zoho

I'm trying to select the minimum document rank for each invoice that *has not already been selected as the minimum document rank for previous invoices*. To accomplish this, I think that I need to know the selected document for all invoicerank < current invoicerank. This is where I'm getting stuck. I would be grateful for any suggestions anybody has!

This is an example of the dataset for 2 clients:

```
clientid    invoicerank documentrank    documentdate
    1           1           1           04/10/2021
    1           1           2           03/03/2021
    1           1           3           02/01/2021
    1           2           1           04/10/2021
    1           2           2           03/03/2021
    1           2           3           02/01/2021
    1           3           1           04/10/2021
    1           3           2           03/03/2021
    1           3           3           02/01/2021
    2           1           null        null
    2           2           1           06/22/2021
    2           2           2           05/04/2021
    2           3           1           06/22/2021
    2           3           2           05/04/2021
```

This is how I want the results to look:

```
clientid    invoicerank documentrank    documentdate
    1           1           1           04/10/2021
    1           2           2           03/03/2021
    1           3           3           02/01/2021
    2           1           null        null
    2           2           1           06/22/2021
    2           3           2           05/04/2021
```

Edit: For this dataset, there is a row for every existing document that could apply to each invoice. The documentrank is selected in another table, it's the dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY documentdate DESC). If the documentrank is null, that means there are no existing documents that could apply to that invoice. So for every invoice, I want the lowest documentrank that hasn't been selected as the lowest documentrank for any previous invoicerank. So for clientid=1 and invoicerank = 2, I want to select the lowest document rank that was not selected as the lowest document rank for invoicerank=1. So invoicerank=1 selects 1 as the minimum. Invoicerank=2 would also select documentrank=1 as the minimum, but since that has already been selected for invoicerank=1 I want it to select documentrank=2.

Edit2: I'm using Zoho Analytics for this query. This limits me to only using select statements and also only having 1 level of nested sub-queries. Case-whens are also not supported inside the window functions. Correlated sub-queries are also not supported.

Comment: Explain your examples. Why those rows? Also which db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that null throws off the numbering. You just need to remember then.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        rank() over (
            partition by clientid
            order by case when documentrank is null then 0 else documentrank
        ) as documentrank2
    from T
)
select * from data where invoicerank = documentrank2
```

I'm assuming there won't be ties anywhere. The following should be equivalent.

```
select *
from (
    select *,
      (
        select count(distinct coalesce(t2.documentrank, 0)) + 1
        from T t2
        where coalesce(t2.documentrank, 0) < coalesce(T.documentrank, 0)
            and t2.clientid = T.clientid
      ) as documentrank2            
    from T
) data
where invoicerank = documentrank2

select *
from T
where invoicerank = (
    select count(distinct coalesce(t2.documentrank, 0)) + 1
    from T t2
    where coalesce(t2.documentrank, 0) < coalesce(T.documentrank, 0)
        and t2.clientid = T.clientid
)

select * from T inner join (
    select clientid,
        count(case when documentrank is null then 1 end) as ofs
    from T
    group by clientid
) t2 on t2.clientid = T.clientid
where T.invoicerank = coalesce(T.documentrank, 0) + t2.ofs

select * from T left outer join (
    select clientid, count(*) as ofs from T
    where documentrank is null
    group by clientid
) t2 on t2.clientid = T.clientid
where T.invoicerank = coalesce(T.documentrank, 0) + coalesce(t2.ofs, 0)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=628e84b8ad3e66b88039ae7c3f3d855c

Comment: Is there a way to write this as a sub-query or using a self-join? I'm using Zoho Analytics, which allows only select statements.

Comment: Zoho also doesn't support correlated sub-queries. Since the where statement for t2 uses a column from the outer query, this format wouldn't work.

Comment: Does the last option not work?